# How to check if a checkbox is checked when iterating through form controls

Tags: vb.net, forms, checkbox

I'm trying to set a registry key for every checkbox on a form, but in the following block of code, I'm receiving the error `'Checked' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.Control'`

Can somebody please help me find out why I'm getting this error?

```
' Create the data for the 'Servers' subkey
Dim SingleControl As Control    ' Dummy to hold a form control
For Each SingleControl In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf SingleControl Is CheckBox Then
        Servers.SetValue(SingleControl.Name, SingleControl.Checked) ' Error happening here
    End If
Next SingleControl
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should convert your control to a CheckBox before using the Checked property.
You use directly the Control variable and this type (Control) doesn't have a Checked property

```
Dim SingleControl As Control    ' Dummy to hold a form control
For Each SingleControl In Me.Controls
    Dim chk as CheckBox = TryCast(SingleControl, CheckBox)
    If chk IsNot Nothing Then
        Servers.SetValue(chk.Name, chk.Checked) 
    End If
Next
```

A better approach could be using  `Enumerable.OfType`

```
Dim chk As CheckBox
For Each chk In Me.Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox)()
    Servers.SetValue(chk.Name, chk.Checked) 
Next
```

this removes the need to convert the generic control to a correct type and test if the conversion was successfully

Comment: Thanks. I figured out that looping that way doesn't loop through the controls in a group, so had to change very slightly to `For Each chk In Me.grpServers.Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox)()`, but both of your examples worked.

Comment: Yes the example just works on the Form controls container. If your checkboxes are on a groupBox then you need to use the controls container of the Groupbox

Answer (score 3):

Try this code,

```
Dim SingleControl As Control
For Each SingleControl In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf SingleControl Is CheckBox Then
        'control does not have property called checked, so we have to cast it into a check box.
        Servers.SetValue(CType(SingleControl, CheckBox).Name, CType(SingleControl, CheckBox).Checked)         End If
Next SingleControl
```

Answer (score 2):

`Checked` is a property of the `CheckBox` class, not its `Control` parent.

You either have to downcast the `Control` into a `Checkbox` in order to access the property `Checked` or you have to store your checkboxes as a `CheckBox` collection not a `Control` collection.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
For Each SingleControl As Control In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf SingleControl Is CheckBox Then
        Dim auxChk As CheckBox = CType(SingleControl, CheckBox)
        Servers.SetValue(auxChk.Name, auxChk.Checked)
    End If
Next SingleControl
```

Answer (score 0):

Use my extension method to get all controls on the form, including controls inside other containers in the form i.e. panels, groupboxes, etc.

```
<Extension()> _
Public Function ChildControls(Of T As Control)(ByVal parent As Control) As List(Of T)
    Dim result As New ArrayList()
    For Each ctrl As Control In parent.Controls
        If TypeOf ctrl Is T Then result.Add(ctrl)
        result.AddRange(ChildControls(Of T)(ctrl))
    Next
    Return result.ToArray().Select(Of T)(Function(arg1) CType(arg1, T)).ToList()
End Function
```

Usage:

```
Me.ChildControls(Of CheckBox). _
    ForEach( _
        Sub(chk As CheckBox)
            Servers.SetValue(chk.Name, chk.Checked)
        End Sub)
```