# Trying to get checked\unchecked value from all checkboxes

Tags: arrays, checkbox, vb.net-2010

I am making a set of checkboxes through an array. I am able to get the checkboxes into my form without issue. I am having trouble getting the checked\unchecked value from the checkboxes into an excel spreadsheet. On the "if checkbox.checked = true then" line I get the error "MissingMemberException was unhandled" "Public member 'checked' on type 'label' not found." I have searched the web and I am having a hard time finding a solution.

Here is the array:

```
X = 30
Y = 75

Dim newCheck As CheckBox

For col As Integer = 1 To TskCnt

    'create a new textbox and set its properties
    newCheck = New CheckBox
    newCheck.Size = New Size(15, 14)
    newCheck.Location = New Point(X, Y)
    newCheck.Name = "Check" & col
    Me.Controls.Add(newCheck)
    Y = Y + 40
Next
```

Here is where I am trying to get the values:

```
For Each CheckBox In Me.Controls
    If CheckBox.Checked = True Then
        oSheet.Range("B" & RowN).Value = "Completed"
    Else
        oSheet.Range("B" & RowN).Value = "Incomplete"
    End If
    RowN = RowN + 1
Next
```

Comment: I found my own solution from another thread on here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15876229/how-to-check-if-a-checkbox-is-checked-when-iterating-through-form-controls

Answer (score 0):

I found my own solution from another thread on here: [How to check if a checkbox is checked when iterating through form controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15876229/how-to-check-if-a-checkbox-is-checked-when-iterating-through-form-controls)

```
    For Each CheckBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox)()
        If CheckBox.Checked = True Then
            oSheet.Range("B" & RowN).Value = "Completed"
        Else
            oSheet.Range("B" & RowN).Value = "Incomplete"
        End If
        RowN = RowN + 1
    Next
```